# Pip installation of pygdal with osx gdal binding fails

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, gdal

I'm trying to run a geoDjango project on OSX Mojave (10.14.5).
Therefore I've installed the dependencies as suggested on the Django docs from [kyngchaos](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/install/#kyngchaos-packages) (tried brew packages as well)

Created my virtualenv which shows

```
New python executable in /Users/ts/.virtualenvs/project_upstream/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /Users/ts/.virtualenvs/project_upstream/bin/python
```

checked gdal with

```
$ gdal-config --version
2.4.1
```

and tried to install pygdal with:

```
pip install pygdal==2.4.1.*
```

which fails with

```
        ERROR: Complete output from command /Users/ts/.virtualenvs/project_upstream/bin/python2.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/j6/wr2vpjzn3698tdsng2j56d7m0000gn/T/pip-install-qTnsBS/pygdal/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/j6/wr2vpjzn3698tdsng2j56d7m0000gn/T/pip-record-vlffrN/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/ts/.virtualenvs/project_upstream/bin/../include/site/python2.7/pygdal:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gnm.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
    copying osgeo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdalnumeric.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
    copying osgeo/osr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
    copying osgeo/ogr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdal_array.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
    copying osgeo/gdalconst.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-2.7/osgeo
    running build_ext
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/Users/ts/.virtualenvs/project_upstream/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/include/gdal -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/include -c gdal_python_cxx11_test.cpp -o gdal_python_cxx11_test.o
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/Users/ts/.virtualenvs/project_upstream/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/include/gdal -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/include -c gdal_python_cxx11_test.cpp -o gdal_python_cxx11_test.o -std=c++11
    building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-2.7/extensions
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/Users/ts/.virtualenvs/project_upstream/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/include/gdal -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/include -c extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-2.7/extensions/gdal_wrap.o -std=c++11 -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/Headers
    In file included from extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:173:
    In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:88:
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:534:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
        register PyObject *obj,     /* Object */
        ^~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:553:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
        register PyObject *obj      /* Object */
        ^~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:575:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
        register const wchar_t *w,  /* wchar_t buffer */
        ^~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:593:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
        register wchar_t *w,        /* wchar_t buffer */
        ^~~~~~~~~
    In file included from extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:173:
    In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:97:
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:173:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
        register PyObject *obj,     /* string or Unicode object */
        ^~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:174:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
        register char **s,          /* pointer to buffer variable */
        ^~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:175:5: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
        register Py_ssize_t *len    /* pointer to length variable or NULL
        ^~~~~~~~~
    7 warnings generated.
    clang++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-2.7/extensions/gdal_wrap.o -L/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/lib -lgdal -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-2.7/osgeo/_gdal.so
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/lib'
    ld: library not found for -lgdal
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'clang++' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/Users/ts/.virtualenvs/project_upstream/bin/python2.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/j6/wr2vpjzn3698tdsng2j56d7m0000gn/T/pip-install-qTnsBS/pygdal/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/j6/wr2vpjzn3698tdsng2j56d7m0000gn/T/pip-record-vlffrN/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/ts/.virtualenvs/project_upstream/bin/../include/site/python2.7/pygdal" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/j6/wr2vpjzn3698tdsng2j56d7m0000gn/T/pip-install-qTnsBS/pygdal/
```

To solve this I've removed all packages and reinstalled. Further tried different packages from brew and kynchaos and instructions found at [this issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233654/install-gdal-python-binding-on-mac) without luck.

**The strange thing is I can install pygdal without problems using no virtualenv!**

Does one know how to overcome this error – what might be the reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by reinstalling virtualenv